# Adding a button to the layout using the .add() method in my first GUI java app

Tags: java, button, javafx

I would like to write my first JAVA GUI aplication but I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it. Could you help me ?

Here is my code.

```
package application;

import java.awt.Button;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;


public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
/*********************************************************************/
        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {


            primaryStage.setTitle("Tytulik");

            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.setLabel("click");


            StackPane layout = new StackPane();
            layout.getChildren().add(btn);

            Scene scena = new Scene(layout, 600, 300);
            primaryStage.setScene(scena);
            primaryStage.show();


        }//start



}//Main
```

The problem appears when I want to add my btn to the layout.

```
layout.getChildren().add(btn);
```

and ECLIPSE tells me this here:

> The method add(Node) in the type List is not applicable for the
>   arguments (Button)

EXLIPSE also tells me that I can change the ***add()*** method to the ***addAll()*** but there is still the same problem.

Comment: you are trying to add an awt button to a javafx component, they don't work that way as far as I know.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your import is incorrect, you have imported

```
import java.awt.Button;
```

where as what you should have imported is :

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to add a **java.awt.Button** to a javafx panel. They are not compatible.

Try using the **javafx.scene.control.Button** instead.